# Spring security - allowing anonymous access

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-boot, spring-security-oauth2

I have implemented Oauth2 in my spring-boot app. In my security-context.xml, I have these lines -

```
<sec:intercept-url pattern="/trusted/**" access="isAnonymous()" />
<sec:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isFullyAuthenticated()" />
```

I want everything under /trusted to be available without authentication. However, I am still prompted for authentication when I try to access /trusted resources (theses are RESTful resources).

Did I miss something else ?

[Edit:] I am running this app with a 'provided' tomcat instance.

Comment: isAnonymous() implies that you have anonymous user configured. I would do something like this:

<intercept-url pattern="/trusted/**" access="permitAll" />

Comment: Stackoverflow is going to award bounty to somebody but I didn't get a working answer.

Answer (score 7):

You just need to replace the trusted intercept expression `access` attribute and it should work:

```
<sec:intercept-url pattern="/trusted/**" filters="none" />
<sec:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isFullyAuthenticated()" />
```

Though since Spring Security 3.1 has deprecated `filters`, you ought to use `http` tags to achieve the same effect:

```
<http pattern="/trusted/**" security="none"/>

<http auto-config='true'>
  <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isFullyAuthenticated()" />
  <form-login login-page='/login.jsp'/>
</http>
```

[You can read more about this here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html#ns-form-and-basic).

Comment: Now I get org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException: An Authentication object was not found in the SecurityContext

Comment: Sounds like you have some other problem with your authentication setup.

Comment: I have modeled after https://github.com/skate056/spring-security-oauth2-google  do you know of some other working example with google oath provider and spring boot?

Answer (score 2):

```
<http>
<intercept-url pattern="/trusted/**" access="ROLE_USER,ROLE_GUEST" />
<intercept-url pattern="/messagePost.htm*" access="ROLE_USER" />
<intercept-url pattern="/messageDelete.htm*" access="ROLE_ADMIN" />
<anonymous username="guest" granted-authority="ROLE_GUEST" />
<remember-me />
</http>
```

> `<anonymous username="guest" granted-authority="ROLE_GUEST" />`

You can define a role like ROLE_GUEST and mention like what the above code does. Any anonymous member can access the url pattern under **ROLE_GUEST**

Answer (score 0):

You configuration is wrong. Now image what's happening, you are telling Spring security to allow anonymous access to everything under `/trusted/**` which is OK, but then you tell it again to restrict all anonymous access under `/**` - which is every path in your application, which obviously restricts access to `/trusted/**` as well.

You need to change your configuration into something like this:

```
<sec:intercept-url pattern="/trusted/**" access="isAnonymous()" />
<sec:intercept-url pattern="/secure/**" access="isFullyAuthenticated()" />
```

and it will work.

Comment: your answer makes sense, but then I am getting this exception -2015-08-17 20:10:30.760 ERROR 18078 --- [io-8080-exec-10] o.s.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter     : Forwarding to error page from request [/monitor/123] due to exception [An Authentication object was not found in the SecurityContext]

org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException: An Authentication object was not found in the SecurityContext